# ¿como rellenar los pixeles de una imagen en android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Quisiera rellenar los "pixeles" de una imagen ejemplo: ***una imagen de 480x800 me gustaria igualarla hasta 800x800 pero sin cambiarle el ancho o el alto***, quisiera hacerlo agregandole mas pixeles pero de un color negro sin que la imagen se deforme

Este es algo del codigo que tengo

```
boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {

           Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 680, 680, true);
           int alto = resized.getHeight();
           int ancho = resized.getWidth();
           String alto1 = String.valueOf(alto);
           String ancho1 = String.valueOf(ancho);


           texto1.setText(alto1);
           texto2.setText(ancho1);

           imagen.setImageBitmap(resized);

           saveBitmap(resized);

       }
   });

}
```

En este bloque convierto la imagen a 680x680 pero algunas imágenes se *deforman* así que la idea es que en vez de cambiarle el tamaño a lo bestia me gustaría rellenar con pixeles negros una de 480x680 me gustaría rellenar el 480 hasta 680 con pixeles extra no si me entienden, así evitaría la deformidad en las imágenes.

*El otro código es para seleccionar la imagen y guardarla en otra carpeta con el tamaño nuevo*

Comment: y que tienes hasta el momento en código ? agrégalo ...

Comment: agregue un poco dime si necesitas algo mas